# gmaps4rails validates before validates presence set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I encountered the following error when I submit an empty address field.

Gmaps4rails::GeocodeInvalidQuery in LocationsController#create 
You must provide an address

My Model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :address, :presence => true

  acts_as_gmappable
  def gmaps4rails_address
    address
  end

  def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<h4>#{name}</h4>" << "<h4>#{address}</h4>"
  end
end
```

The question why it never validates the address field presence or not and directly throw error?

Comment: Hi, just noted your question. I'm gonna release a new version this week end including custom infoboxes + a fix to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in `0.8.7` it will now normally add error to the address field.

Gmaps4rails already checks whether or not the address is empty or nil. It's part of the options described [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization).

You can, for instance, set your own validation message this way:

```
acts_as_gmappable :msg => "Errrrrrrror"
```

Comment: what if I don't want it to validate the address field. or skip the validation?